# Video watermarking with ffmpeg (output video size too big )

Tags: video, ffmpeg

i am running ffmpeg on video of size around 2 Mb and after watermarking them size of my video file is around 13-17 Mb. AM i doing something wrong. Please Help

My code is

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\flask\mobile_form\Videos\20191231140058_987654567.mp4" -i "C:\flask\mobile_form\resizeLogo.jpg" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10,drawtext=text=Hello:fontsize=24:x=main_w-200:y=main_h-100,drawtext=text=World:fontsize=24:x=main_w-200:y=main_h-60" "C:\flask\mobile_form\waterMark\second.mp4"
```

This is my full log, It is not giving any error but i want my output file to be smaller.

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-01-15-0dc0837 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200111
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
  libavcodec     58. 65.103 / 58. 65.103
  libavformat    58. 35.102 / 58. 35.102
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 71.100 /  7. 71.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
```

Continued

```
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1

  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1727 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 255x122 [SAR 120:120 DAR 255:122], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
[Parsed_drawtext_1 @ 000001ba5309d4c0] Using "C:/WINDOWS/fonts/mingliub.ttc"
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
[Parsed_drawtext_2 @ 000001ba53051640] Using "C:/WINDOWS/fonts/mingliub.ttc"
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (vp8) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (mjpeg) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
  drawtext (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (opus (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
[Parsed_drawtext_1 @ 000001ba53c06280] Using "C:/WINDOWS/fonts/mingliub.ttc"
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
[Parsed_drawtext_2 @ 000001ba53c40d40] Using "C:/WINDOWS/fonts/mingliub.ttc"
[swscaler @ 000001ba53caf380] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 000001ba5304e240] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000001ba5304e240] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000001ba5304e240] profile High, level 5.2, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001ba5304e240] 264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=15 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00

Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\Users\3427521kar\Desktop\New folder (2)\output30.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 1k fps, 16k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.65.103 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:

[libx264 @ 000001ba5304e240] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001ba5304e240] ref P L0: 77.1% 13.5%  8.3%  1.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001ba5304e240] ref B L0: 75.0% 24.5%  0.5%
[libx264 @ 000001ba5304e240] ref B L1: 94.1%  5.9%
[libx264 @ 000001ba5304e240] kb/s:1380.55
[aac @ 000001ba53067100] Qavg: 129.494
```

here is the full log of my code

Comment: Show the full log from your command.

Comment: I have edited my question and add full log with it.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? my case video became double size after added watermark.

Answer (score 0):

We can use encode to H264 video.
Try to add:

```
-vcodec libx264
```

And we can choose bitrate by:

```
-b 200K
```

(For example)

Comment: i tried using -vcodec libx264 but it didn't help. And using -b 200k ruined the video